# could not convert string to float: ''

Tags: python, tkinter

He estado creando esta interfaz simple usando Tkinter con python:
Tengo este codigo:

```
from tkinter import *

def calculoimc():
    resultadoimc.set(float(metros.get()) / float(kilogramos.get()))

raiz = Tk()

frame = Frame(raiz)
frame.pack()

kilogramos = StringVar()
metros = StringVar()
resultadoimc = StringVar()
```

------------ Pantalla ------------------

```
peso = Label(frame, text="Peso (kg): ")
PesoPantalla = Entry(frame, textvariable=kilogramos)

altura = Label(frame, text="Altura (mts): ")
AlturaPantalla = Entry(frame, textvariable=metros)

res = Label(frame, text="IMC es: ")
resPantalla = Entry(frame, textvariable=resultadoimc)
resPantalla.config(justify="center", state="disabled")


calcular = Button(frame, text="Calcular", command=calculoimc())

raiz.mainloop()
```

y me genera este error:

```
resultadoimc.set(float(metros.get()) / float(kilogramos.get()))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

No sé a que se refiera exactamente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que cuando ejecutas tu programa tu función `calculoimc()` esta siendo llamada y ejecutada, ya que cuando se la pasaste al botón le agregaste los paréntesis y eso hace que tu función se ejecute inmediatamente y al mismo tiempo esta ocasiona una excepción.

entonces como se ejecuta al iniciar el programa, tu función lo que hace es actualizar el entry, y para eso tiene que obtener los valores de los demás entrys y convertirlos, pero como los campos están vacíos estos se toman como string vacíos y he ahí el problema.

aquí tu error

```
calcular = Button(frame, text="Calcular", command=calculoimc()) # funcion que se ejecuta al iniciar el programa
```

función que espera a que el botón sea presionado para ejecutarse.

```
calcular = Button(frame, text="Calcular", command=calculoimc) # funcion sin parentesis
```

también me doy cuenta que no tienes ningún widget posicionado, para posicionarlos puedes usar uno de estos 3 métodos `pack()`, `grid()` o `place()`

```
from tkinter import *

def calculoimc():
    resultadoimc.set(float(metros.get()) / float(kilogramos.get()))

raiz = Tk()

frame = Frame(raiz)
frame.pack()

kilogramos = StringVar()
metros = StringVar()
resultadoimc = StringVar()

peso = Label(frame, text="Peso (kg): ").pack()
PesoPantalla = Entry(frame, textvariable=kilogramos).pack()

altura = Label(frame, text="Altura (mts): ").pack()
AlturaPantalla = Entry(frame, textvariable=metros).pack()

res = Label(frame, text="IMC es: ").pack()
#resPantalla.config(justify="center", state="disabled")
resPantalla = Entry(frame, textvariable=resultadoimc).pack()
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Observación

El error se debe a que ha recibido un string vacío `''` (<-- está vacío)

puedes intentar tomar la variable y cuando está vacía replazarla por '0'.

```py
'0' if len(text)==0 else text 

# Ejemplo:
float('0' if len(metros.get())==0 else metros.get() )
```

o podrías "manejar" el error con try:except

```py
def calculoimc():
    try:
        resultadoimc.set(float(metros.get()) / float(kilogramos.get()))
    except:
        print('No se asignó valor')
```

o podrías simplemente garantizar que nunca esté vacío el campo. (Actualmente no sé como obligar a rellenar un campo en tkinter... y parece que no hay forma: [How to make a tkinter Entry field mandatory to enter some text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271056/how-to-make-a-tkinter-entry-field-mandatory-to-enter-some-text))